# Unable to run "npm start" shows error. how to resolve?

Tags: node.js, npm

Getting error while running comment "npm start" in windows 10.

[showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejv0p.png)

Package.json

[Packages.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vrGR.png)

```
Log
```

- 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
- 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
- 1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
- 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
- 2 info using npm@4.2.0
- 3 info using node@v6.9.3
- 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
- 5 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~prestart: hello-world@0.1.0
- 6 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
- 7 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: hello-world@0.1.0
- 8 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
- 9 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\vkarutha\Documents\React\hello-world\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\OSD-ShellApplications;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Cisco\software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ssh communications security\ssh Secure Shell;C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
- 10 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\vkarutha\Documents\React\hello-world
- 11 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --hot' ]
- 12 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 4294967295  signal: null
- 13 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
- 14 verbose stack Error: hello-world@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
- 14 verbose stack Exit status 4294967295
- 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
- 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
- 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
- 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
- 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
- 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
- 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
- 14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
- 15 verbose pkgid hello-world@0.1.0
- 16 verbose cwd C:\Users\vkarutha\Documents\React\hello-world
- 17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
- 18 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\vkarutha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
- 19 error node v6.9.3
- 20 error npm  v4.2.0
- 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
- 22 error errno 4294967295
- 23 error hello-world@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
- 23 error Exit status 4294967295
- 24 error Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
- 24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
- 24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hello-world package,
- 24 error not with npm itself.
- 24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
- 24 error     webpack-dev-server --hot
- 24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
- 24 error     npm bugs hello-world
- 24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
- 24 error     npm owner ls hello-world
- 24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
- 25 verbose exit [ 4294967295, true ]

webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have `webpack-dev-server` installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `npm run start` alt `npm r start`

navigate to the same folder where the package.json is located
type `npm install` to get all the dependencies. 
type `npm run start`

Do you have the `webpack.config.js`?

Could be malformed webpack config: This is how mine looks, (replace with your stuff):

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('src/main'),
    entry: {
        myapp: './dependencies.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/dev'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)(.*)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }

};
```

Comment: is there anything wrong with start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`

Comment: attached my webpack.config.js

Comment: Check that node_modules folder has been created in the same directory as you run npm install

Comment: Yes, It is there in the same directory.

Comment: Your webpack config looks different from the basic examples at webpack homepage, and from mine. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much . Server started but getting some error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your webpack.config.js file. You need to export the config object like this-

```
module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```