# npm run verbose stack Error: learn-starter@0.1.0 start: `env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.uat next start`

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new in angular and tried lots of answers and questions at google but not getting solution.

I refer below questions:

[refer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69685019/verbose-stack-error-functions-start-npm-run-shell)
[refer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754354/npm-install-giving-error-after-so-many-warn/62760196#62760196)
[refer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754354/npm-install-giving-error-after-so-many-warn/62760196#62760196)
[refer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245185/unable-to-run-npm-start-shows-error-how-to-resolve)

Below are error details:

**Logs:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~prestart: learn-starter@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: learn-starter@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\project\cu\service-portal-fe\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;D:\soft\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%AppData%\npm;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.9.1\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.9.1\node_modules\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.9.1\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\node_modules\.bin;C:\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.9.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\node-gyp-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;D:\soft\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\.windows-build-tools\python27\Scripts\;C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\npm;
9 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\project\cu\service-portal-fe
10 silly lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.uat next start' ]
11 silly lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: learn-starter@0.1.0 start: `env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.uat next start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ankit.aggarwal1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid learn-starter@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\project\cu\service-portal-fe
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v14.20.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error learn-starter@0.1.0 start: `env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.uat next start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the learn-starter@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "cypress/support/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:ci": "bash cypress/ci-linux.sh",
    "build": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/$npm_config_country/.env.$npm_config_env npm run-script ui:build",
    "build:win": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/%npm_config_country%/.env.%npm_config_env% npm run-script ui:build",
    "automation": "cypress run --env type=base --headless --browser chrome",
    "automation:local": "cypress run --record false",
    "cypress:run": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
    "cypress:test": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress run",
    "cypress:ci:win": "npm run build:local & start npm run start:local & wait-on http://localhost:3000/portal-6K6X4ezt24GFYU8k/login",
    "build:local": "npm run build:win --country=ASIA --env=uat",
    "start:local": "npm run start:win --country=ASIA --env=uat",
    "visual:update": "npx cypress run --env type=base --config record=false",
    "start": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.uat next start",
    "start:win": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/%npm_config_country%/.env.%npm_config_env% next start",
    "start:custom": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/$npm_config_country/.env.$npm_config_env node server.js",
    "start:custom-win": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/%npm_config_country%/.env.%npm_config_env% node server.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "ui:build": "next build",
    "dev-AT": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/%npm_config_country%/.env.%npm_config_env% next dev --port=8000",
    "dev": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/%npm_config_country%/.env.%npm_config_env% next dev",
    "dev:local-EU": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/EUROPE/.env.local next dev",
    "dev:local-ASIA": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/ASIA/.env.local next dev",
    "dev:linux": "env-cmd -x -f ./environments/$npm_config_country/.env.$npm_config_env next dev",
    "serve": "prettier --write . && eslint . --fix **/*.{js,jsx} && env-cmd -f ./environments/PH/.env.local next build && next start",
    "lint": "eslint --fix **/*.{js,jsx}",
    "prettify": "prettier --write .",
    "docker:remove": "docker rm service-portal-fe",
    "docker:start:win": "docker build --build-arg PROFILE_PARAM=%npm_config_env% --build-arg COUNTRY_PARAM=%npm_config_country% --tag service-portal-fe:1.0 . && docker run --publish 8000:80 --detach --name service-portal-fe service-portal-fe:1.0",
    "docker:start": "docker build --build-arg PROFILE_PARAM=$npm_config_env --build-arg COUNTRY_PARAM=$npm_config_country --tag service-portal-fe:1.0 . && docker run --publish 8000:80 --detach --name service-portal-fe service-portal-fe:1.0",
    "delete:reportFolder": "rm -rf mochawesome-report/",
    "test:cli": "npm run delete:reportFolder && cypress run",
    "merge:reports": "mochawesome-merge mochawesome-report/*.json > cypress-combined-report.json",
    "create:html:report": "npm run merge:reports && marge --reportDir TestReport cypress-combined-report.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "framer-motion": "^3.6.7",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.14",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "neat-csv": "^5.2.0",
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "next-connect": "^0.12.2",
    "next-images": "^1.8.4",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^6.0.2",
    "next-safe": "^3.3.0",
    "parse-markdown-table": "^0.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^6.0.0",
    "react-datetime": "^3.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-floating-label-input": "^4.3.4",
    "react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.4",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.11",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "xss": "^1.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.19.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.10.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.28",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-visual-regression": "^1.7.0",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.8.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.5.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.4.0",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^1.2.7",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "wait-on": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint --config ./.eslintrc --fix",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "nyc": {
    "include": [
      "**/shared/**"
    ],
    "all": false,
    "cache": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": false,
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ],
    "report-dir": "./tests-report",
    "reporter": [
      "html",
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```

NPM version: **6.14.17**
Node Version: **v14.20.1**
NVM version: **14.20.1**

Please help me on this issue. Thanks